# Wordpress is adding <!— page-who-we-are.php --> above html

Tags: comments, templates

Wordpress is adding this comment above all HTML on my site which is causing problems in IE in which the site won't render properly at all.

How do I stop WP adding this?

Tried disabling all plugins but nothing

Comment: Which Theme are you using?

Comment: "WordPress" (i.e. core) doesn't add much of anything to the front-end, and certainly not `<!-- page-who-we-are.php-->`. 99.9% certain your *Theme* is adding that. Look in `header.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to search for files by content and search inside wp-content folder of your WordPress for this string: "page-who-we-are.php" - you'll locate the string and you can remove it.

To search files by content on Windows, see [Best way to *confidently* search files and contents in Windows without using an indexing service?](https://superuser.com/questions/26593/best-way-to-confidently-search-files-and-contents-in-windows-without-using-an)